# Find a diffrent minimal spanning tree for a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, spanning-trees

For my homework I have a problem that I can't solve and it makes me wonder about 2 different MST:

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph that has a minimum spanning tree $T$.
>
> I want to find another minimum spanning tree $T'$ that has at least 1 different edge $e'$
> such that the weight of $e'$ is differ from any weight of edges in $T$.

If $T'$ doesn't exist I can claim that every 2 different MST must have the same weight for each edge.

My intuition says that this claim is wrong but on the other hand I can't find example of $T'$ to contradict this claim.

Comment: What exactly is your claim? If $T'$ does not exist, then $T$ is unique, sure. But [$T'$ *can* exist](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12048/graph-has-two-three-different-minimal-spanning-trees?rq=1), [under certain conditions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10728/how-many-minimal-spanning-trees-are-there-when-all-edge-costs-are-distinct). [They are all similar](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2204/98), though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find such a MST. Every two minimal spanning trees must have the same multiset of edge-weights.
Actually you can find the proof in the link that Raphael added:

[Do the minimum spanning trees of a weighted graph have the same number of edges with a given weight?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/do-the-minimum-spanning-trees-of-a-weighted-graph-have-the-same-number-of-edges)